# What can the Pyro return to sender using the compression blast?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

What exactly can the Pyro’s compression blast affect? I’ve reflected rockets back at soldiers, but I’ve had very sketchy luck trying to bounce other things back at enemy players.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**You can reflect:**

- [image: Reflected Rocket kill icon] Soldier Rockets (all types)
- [image: Reflected Flare kill icon] Pyro Flares (all types)
- [image: Reflected Grenade kill icon] Demoman Grenades (all types)
- [image: Reflected Sticky kill icon] Demoman Sticky Bombs (Sticky Bomb Launcher/Scottish Resistance)†
- [image: Reflected Arrow kill icon] Huntsman arrows (which can headshot enemies)
- [image: Reflected Sandman ball kill icon] Sandman Baseballs
- [image: Reflected Sandman ball kill icon] Wrap Assassin Ornaments
- Crusader's Crossbow arrows
- Rescue Ranger bolts (will damage opposing buildings but not repair friendly ones)
- Mad Milk
- Jarate
- Level 3 Sentry Gun Rockets

When you reflect projectiles they are promoted to minicrits (if they weren't), change sides with your team and ownership to you (with the exception (†) of stickies). This means, however, that they will still do splash damage to you should they explode too close. As for stickies You can still push those off points and doors, however, or even push them below the demoman's feet.

**You cannot reflect:**

- Hitscan shots — anything which is a “bullet” and appears as streaks rather than projectiles
- Syringe Gun needles
- Bison and Pomson projectiles (you *can* reflect Cow Mangler beams, however.)

Comment: What about the Scout's baseball? Also, I heard jars can be blasted away as well :)

Comment: @Oak I've never seen a Scout's baseball reflected. Jarate jars can be, but not sure about Mad Milk. – Powerlord

Comment: Scout's baseball, mad milk, and even sentry gun rockets can be reflected.

Comment: You were missing the original Jar-based Karate, so I added it in. And yes, I'll second that Scout's Baseballs can be reflected. I once got an assist on my own teammate in this manner (ball reflected into teammate, pyro proceeds to burn said teammate, +1 assist for me?!)

Comment: Great group effort guys

Comment: Sorry about that, I was at work earlier and has to get badp to post a response... I kinda forgot about several things (sentry rockets, jarate, mad milk, baseballs)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention: You can headshot with reflected Huntsman arrows. :D

Comment: There's even a special kill icon for it!

Comment: I'm relatively certain the icon for a reflected arrow headshot is now in use.  I can't provide proof at the moment, though

Comment: What about The Flying Guillotine, Crit-a-Cola, and the Bonk! Atomic Punch?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Crit-a-Cola and Bonk! Atomic Punch are drank, not thrown.

Comment: @badp OK, for some reason I thought they could be thrown like Jarate. But what about the Flying Guillotine?