# Pyro Tactics and Tips?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the secret to playing Pyro?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/whats-the-secret-to-playing-pyro)

Jump into pub.
Select Pyro.
Die.
Die.
DIE.

I would like to know as many tips as possible for playing Pyro, I'm decent with every class but Pyro. what is that thing I'm missing?

I try flanking, but I always die to a heavy, or a demo.

I sorta just suck.

**Bottom line: Post your tips loadouts, etc for the Pyro.**

Answer (score 2):

I suggest another Pyro tips-and-tricks question already above, but to quickly address this:

> I try flanking, but I always die to a heavy, or a demo.

Make sure you're using the Backburner and getting them from behind, that's the quickest way to bring tough opponents down.

If a Demoman starts firing grenades (not stickies) at you, you can also try [deflecting](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Compression_blast) them back at him.

And generally, just be at corners or hallways that people forget about; when they show up, you can drop by and make some short work of them.

Comment: Um, although deflecting can save your skin, don't expect to get any kills with it unless you are either VERY good at air blasting stuff like huntsman arrows, or you're reflecting soldier rockets.

Comment: @Nicholas1024: Yeah it takes a little getting the hang of, but I deflect most grenades to neutralize them more than anything else, really.

Comment: Thing to remember about deflecting with Backburner is that it costs 50 ammo...

Comment: Doesn't mean you shouldn't use it if it's going to save your ass (or your Medic's). Sure it doesn't run down as fast if you use flames, but you have to get pretty close to do that.